# Set maximum number of characters for MahApps NumericUpDown control

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, numericupdown

I am using the `NumericUpDown` control from MahApps, because of its +/- buttons and the ability to set the maximum/minimum allowed value. I now need to somehow limit the number of character, that can be input to the box.

For a standard `TextBox` this would be done with the `MaxLength` property, but this property does not exist for the `NumericUpDown` control.

Am I missing something? Is there some other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such property, but you can easily extend NumericUpDown and add it. BTW, when you focus out, it checks the Maximum allowed value and the input value.

**C#**

```
    using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Input;

    namespace TestApp.Controls
    {
        class ExtendedNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
        {
            public int MaxLenght
            {
                get { return (int)GetValue(MaxLenghtProperty); }
                set { SetValue(MaxLenghtProperty, value); }
            }

            public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLenghtProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MaxLenght), typeof(int), typeof(ExtendedNumericUpDown), new PropertyMetadata(10));


            protected override void OnPreviewTextInput(TextCompositionEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Handled = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)e.OriginalSource).Text.Length >= MaxLenght;

                base.OnPreviewTextInput(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<ctrl:ExtendedNumericUpDown Minimum="0" Maximum="100" MaxLenght="3"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Alex's answer, you can take it one step further by creating a behavior. The behavior can be used by many different types of controls and you don't need to subclass `NumericUpDown`

```
    public class MaxCharactersBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {
        public int MaxCharacters { get; set; }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += AssociatedObject_PreviewTextInput;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= AssociatedObject_PreviewTextInput;
        }

        private void AssociatedObject_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = ((System.Windows.Controls.TextBox)e.OriginalSource).Text.Length >= MaxCharacters;
        }
    }
```

```
<mah:NumericUpDown Width="150" Maximum="999" Minimum="0">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MaxCharactersBehavior MaxCharacters="3" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</mah:NumericUpDown>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `NumericUpDown` control accepts `Maximum` and `Minimum` arguments,

```
<Controls:NumericUpDown Minimum="0"  Maximum="{Binding TotalPages}"/>
```

If you can't find them, try to update the NuGet package of MahApps.